# Unusual Vector space Anton exercise 16

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the set of positive real numbers, let $u = \vec{u}$ and $v = \vec{v}$ be any vectors (i.e., positive
real numbers) in V, and let $k$ be any scalar.
Define the operations on $V$ to be:
$$
u + v = u*v \ \ \ \ \text{[Vector addition is numerical multiplication.]} \\
k*u = u^k \ \ \ \ \ \text{[Scalar multiplication is numerical exponentiation.]}
$$
Verify the Axioms of a vector space.

I'm specifically having trouble showing multiplicative commutativity.
For example, this can't be reasonable: u*k = k^u

Comment: What have you tried? Can you write down what the definition of multiplicative commutativity for the multiplication as defined here?

Comment: On MathSE, we'd like to see effort. What have you tried.

Comment: What "multiplicative commutativity"? There's no such thing for vector spaces.

Comment: Having read my entire question would have informed you that k is a scalar.  I don't understand why my question has a negative vote.

Answer (score 0):

For a vector space $V$, a vector $\vec{v} \in V$ and a set of scalars $c, d$ the multiplicative axiom state that

- $0.\vec{v} = \vec{0}$
- $1.\vec{v} = \vec{v}$
- $(cd).\vec{v} = c(d.\vec{v})$

In your case, it is easy to see that the $1^{st}$ two axioms are being satisfied. Coming to the third one,
In LHS we have $(cd).\vec{v} = (\vec{v})^{cd}$, whereas in RHS we have $c(d.\vec{v}) = c.(\vec{v})^d = ((\vec{v})^d)^c = (\vec{v})^{cd}$. So both LHS and RHS are the same.

Comment: Isn't the "zero vector" of this vector space the real number $1$? The definition of $+$ precludes the zero vector being the real number $0$, since $0*v\neq v$ for any nonzero $v$.

Comment: Good Point!!! I will edit

Comment: @walkar Now you may upvote